# How to find the first char after the first blank line in a text file

Tags: regex

Here is my [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/5R6otS/1)

how can I find the start of the file i.e. the first char in the first word `But`

```
file: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 19 Jan 2017 22:22:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Wed, 11 Jan 2017 20:54:33 GMT
ETag: "3215b4-a7-545d7cec7fb4c"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 167
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain

But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

This is my attempt but I can't get by that first blank line:
`\n\s*\n`

Comment: [**`(?:[\w-]+:.*\R)+\R+\K(.)`**](https://regex101.com/r/5R6otS/2)

Answer (score 2):

To be more specific, beside matching all header information at once you can match two newlines first then a letter:

```
(?:[\w-]+:.*[\r\n])+[\r\n](.)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ho8GHx/1)

`B` is hold by first capturing group.

Answer (score 2):

What if you look for two newlines in a row and then capture the first character after them:

[`\R\R(.)`](https://regex101.com/r/5R6otS/3)

Answer (score 1):

The first non white space after two linebreaks:

```
\R\R\h*(\S)
```

Where:

- `\R`: any kind of linebreak
- `\h*`: 0 or more horizontal spaces
- `(\S)`: A non space character, captured in group 1